# UI for background image customization

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I'm totally new to React. I'm taking a course where my task is to make a UI where if you load an image, you can mark a rectangular area on this background image. The vertices of this rectangle must be stored in pixels. I also need to store the rectangles position relative to the background image in the form of its top left corner and bottom right corner - it needs to be given in %. So starting from the top left of the background image how much percent of the background do we need to go right and bottom to reach the top left corner of this rectangle. The task goes on but I would love some help for this first part.

I know how to load images and make basic programs in React using TypeScript but I don't really know how to begin here.

I have been using an image editor plugin for this project as it is going to be needed later on, it can draw rectangles, but I'm not sure how to store the vertices.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.